# How to test hypothesis on very rare count data type?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, count-data

I have two samples (10K each) of count data type (0,1,2,3,4,5...) with 
P(x=0) = 75-85%

when we check the bins of x > 0 , 
The P(x = 1 ) ~= 0.6 and P(x=2) ~= 0.3 for both.
 The higher the number the more rare it is

a smaller samples from similar population (another class) :

```
    --  A        B
count   7247    7228
mean 0.124741   0.150802
std  1.448501   2.420841
min   0          0
25%   0          0
50%   0          0
75%   0          0
max   61         117
```

[image]
what is the best way check if A and B are coming from different populations ?
The main goal here is to determine if condition B increasing the mean

Comment: What null hypothesis? What alternative hypothesis?

Comment: No significant difference between specified population

Comment: If your hypothesis is not about means why are you telling us what the means are?

Comment: the metric that i'm using to evaluate sample A vs ample B is the mean. but your point is right , my hypothesis is about the means .

Comment: How does the upper bound of 5 on the count arise?

Comment: There is no theoretical   upper bound ,but if i check the frequency of each bin (>0) , 90% are 1/ 2 ( 60%,30% respectively). It seems that  i didn't provided enough information about what i'm  testing

Comment: oh, okay. so the possible values are 0,1,2,3,4,5,... -- thanks, that can make a difference to likely potential suggestions. Yes, you didn't specify enough information; more questions may arise. It would help if you could edit some of the additional information into your question.

Comment: Alright . added all the additional information .. thanks!

Comment: You might try rebinning the data into larger bins to get some idea of what the distributions are. However, since you do not characterize what the data comes from, it is hard to be sure how to treat it. What is it, generically speaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

1. your samples are large
2. you do not specify anything about the distribution

it makes sense to consider Z-test ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test). To implement it in Python, you can follow the instructions here:
http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Python-Workshop/stats_calculations.html
(Search for Z-test).

Comment: I've first tried using two sample t test for that, but since most of the data samples are 0 , i was troubled by the point that my sample distribution (according to central limit ) can not be normal . Do you think that the frequency of the zeros (can be up to 85%) can biased the test results? since i'm interested at the changes done on x>0 as well .

Comment: i've implement the ztest using statsmodels and compared it to 2 sample t test and the test statistic is identical  . thanks  a lot!

Comment: This is not surprising - t test and z test tend to be identical with large samples. If you are interested in the comparisons of means only, then the result is satisfactory (due to the central limit theorem).

Comment: Btw, could you plot histograms of your data and share them with us? Another questions: what is the maximum in the datasets? what is the most rare value?

Comment: Yes, i've add them to the main question.